# Ansible: using role dependencies

Tags: ansible, configuration, webserver, system-administration

Trying to create a role for installing and configuring dokuwiki.
Dokuwiki uses php.
I've made the choice to impose Apache for this particular role.

My understanding is that the proper way to install those packages would be to use roles that would deal with the various aspects of installing and configuring those tools.

Therefore, I'm using `geerlingguy.apache` and `geerlingguy.php`.
The tasks and variables in my role are organized accordingly.

My role tree:

```
ansible-role-dokuwiki
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── roles
│   ├── geerlingguy.apache
│   └── geerlingguy.php
├── tasks
│   ├── download_dokuwiki.yml
│   ├── main.yml
│   └── selinux_config.yml
├── vars
│   ├── Debian.yml
│   └── RedHat.yml
├── LICENSE
└── README.m
```

`ansible-role-dokuwiki/tasks/main.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Selects PHP:7.4 (RedHat)
  command: "dnf module enable -y php:7.4"
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"

- name: Install php
  include_role:
    name: geerlingguy.php

- name: Install apache
  include_role:
    name: geerlingguy.apache

# The rest of the tasks goes here
```

I've created this playbook, that uses my role, to install dokuwiki:

`server_setup.yaml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - roles/dokuwiki
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR! the role 'geerlingguy.apache' was not found in [several local paths]

The error appears to be in '/path/to/ansible-role-dokuwiki/meta/main.yml': line 3, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

dependencies:
  - role: geerlingguy.apache
    ^ here
```

Seems like I'm missing something essential in the way to deal with dependencies and/or the way to make several roles interact together...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Looks like tou didn’t install those roles.

Comment: Right now I don't want to install those roles: I want to keep them in my tree. As I mentioned: they are both in `ansible-role-dokuwiki/roles`

Comment: That’s a really bad idea, but either way, I would suspect you are clashing with namespace resolutions of roles name. Try changing both the files and the import, replacing the dot by, for example, a dash. I.e. `geerlingguy-apache` instead of `geerlingguy.apache`

Comment: So the problem is indeed that I mention those roles as dependencies in my `meta/main.yml`. Which I shouldn't I guess? So the way ansible deals with this is that someone that downloads my role should go to meta file to look for the dependencies by him/herself? No automatic procedure?

Comment: I think I can see why it would be a bad idea but, on the other hand, my role would still work even if the the apache and php role change. There is a balance to find, isn't it?

Comment: It's confusing to me that ansible it looking for those roles in my playbook directory, even though there are only mentioned in my role

Comment: _on the other hand, my role would still work even if the the apache and php role change_  > that’s exactly why you should pin your dependencies, which is exactly what galaxy allows you to do, indeed : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-multiple-roles-from-a-file

Comment: _It's confusing to me that ansible it looking for those roles in my playbook directory_ > because roles resolution is just a list of path. If you want a true role dependency, you should look for https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies

Comment: ok got it. Sry for the newbie questions. I actually am a newbie at doing things properly with ansible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257248/discussion-between-duncan-and---).